# Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, constructor

For whatever reason, when I attempt to set an instance of a contract in a javascript file, I get the following message in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor
```

At first, I suspected I had a problem with properly setting my Web3 instance, but when I run:

```
console.log(web3);
```

The console shows that I the web3 instance is set.

I try and set my the contract instance using the following code:

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract([//json array]);
```

Any tips for solving this?

Comment: This is for v1.x, you're probably still on v0.x. You can check it via `npm ls web3`. For v0.x, remove the `new` and change `Contract` with an upper-case C to `contract` with a lower-case c.

Comment: Thank you goodvibration, that solved my problem. How do I give you credit for the answer?

Comment: I added it as an answer, so you can give it a credit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for v1.x, you're probably still on v0.x.

You can check it via `npm ls web3`.

For v0.x, remove the `new` and change `Contract` to `contract`.