# how to let the user use Ethereum DApp Without having wallet

Tags: web3js, wallets, web3-providers

I have a question regarding Ethereum and DAPP ..

I have a smart contract that basically store a document and I integrated it with a user interface that let the user go to the website and search for that document .. very simple idea.

the problem is and correct me if i'm wrong .. the process of storing the document to the Ethereum blockchain require a gas but the process of getting that document is gasless ..

and I think that the user need to have a wallet to use the website and search for the document .. even if the process does not require any gas

Am I right? because that what I understand

and if I am right .. is there a way where the user can enter and use the website without having to install a wallet or doing anything beside searching for the document that he need?

I'm using web3.js

and i tried this code:

```
var contract
var addresse = //my contract addresse;
var api = // api ;

contract = new web3.eth.Contract(api, addresse);
```

but i got :

> "Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor"

Comment: Regarding the TypeError: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72689/uncaught-typeerror-web3-eth-contract-is-not-a-constructor

Comment: yes the problem was the web3 version is 0 .. so I replace `web3.eth.Contract` with `web3.eth.contract` and it work but now it say :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEntity' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right, you can interact with a smart contract without having a wallet.

By connecting with a Provider, so you will only have read-only access to the Contract, without sending a transaction (Can’t alter the smart contract state).

By creating an instance of the contract:

- Web3: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#
- Ethers: https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html#connecting-to-a-contract

Comment: I updated my Question .. Please chuck it out.

Comment: Try this `contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(contractAddress);`

Btw, be careful not to confuse ABI and API, think of "ABI" as an "API" at a low level.

Comment: it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: ABI is not defined

Comment: you named it `api`

Comment: yeah sorry about that .. now when the user try to search or read its says 
` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property isEntity of undefined ` where `isEntity` is a function in my contract

Comment: please open a new thread with more details and code, as we're moving off the subject.

Comment: I opened a new thread with the full code. Please check it out